# Not able to fetch data from database by using ajax in java

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, jsp, servlets

hi i am implementing program which fetch data from database in java with ajax. but unfortunately it is not retireving output here is my code. program is running succesfully but not able to display database data from it.

index.jsp

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>AJAX JsonArray Example</title>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oxygen' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<style type="text/css">
table, td, th
{
border:1px solid green;

font-family: 'Oxygen', sans-serif;

}

th
{

background-color:green;

color:white;

}
body
{
 text-align: center;

}
.container

{

 margin-left: auto;

 margin-right: auto;

 width: 40em;

}
</style>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#tablediv").hide();
     $("#showTable").click(function(event){
           $.get('PopulateTable',function(responseJson) {
            if(responseJson!=null){
                $("#countrytable").find("tr:gt(0)").remove();
                var table1 = $("#countrytable");
                $.each(responseJson, function(key,value) {
                     var rowNew = $("<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>");
                        rowNew.children().eq(0).text(value['code']);
                        rowNew.children().eq(1).text(value['name']);
                        rowNew.children().eq(2).text(value['continent']);
                        rowNew.children().eq(3).text(value['region']);
                        rowNew.children().eq(4).text(value['population']);
                        rowNew.children().eq(5).text(value['capital']);
                        rowNew.appendTo(table1);
                });
                }
            });
            $("#tablediv").show();         
  });     
});
</script>
</head>
<body class="container">
<h1>AJAX Retrieve Data from Database in Servlet and JSP using JSONArray</h1>
<input type="button" value="Show Table" id="showTable"/>
<div id="tablediv">
<table cellspacing="0" id="countrytable">
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">Code</th>
        <th scope="col">Name</th>
        <th scope="col">Continent</th>
        <th scope="col">Region</th>
        <th scope="col">Population</th>
       <th scope="col">Capital</th>         
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

FetchData.jsp

```
  /*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */


import Countries.Countries;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Properties;


public class FetchData {

private static Connection connection = null;


public static Connection getConnection() {

        if (connection != null)

            return connection;

        else {

            try {

                Properties prop = new Properties();

                InputStream inputStream = FetchData.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/db.properties");

                prop.load(inputStream);

                String driver = prop.getProperty("jdbc:mysql:");

                String url = prop.getProperty("localhost:3306/country_db");

                String user = prop.getProperty("root");

                String password = prop.getProperty("");

                Class.forName(driver);

                connection = DriverManager.getConnection("localhost:3306/country_db", "root", "");

            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();

            } catch (SQLException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();

            } catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();

            }

            return connection;

       }



    }


    public static ArrayList<Countries> getAllCountries() {

     connection = FetchData.getConnection();

        ArrayList<Countries> countryList = new ArrayList<Countries>();

        try {

            Statement statement = connection.createStatement();

            ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("select * from country");


            while(rs.next()) {

             Countries country=new Countries();

             country.setCode(rs.getString("Code"));

             country.setName(rs.getString("Name"));

                country.setContinent(rs.getString("Continent"));

                country.setRegion(rs.getString("Region"));

             country.setPopulation(rs.getInt("Population"));

             country.setCapital(rs.getString("Capital"));

             countryList.add(country);

            }

        } catch (SQLException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }



        return countryList;

    }

}
```

PopulateTable.java

```
    /*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

import Countries.Countries;


import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.JsonArray;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


@WebServlet("/PopulateTable")

public class PopulateTable extends HttpServlet {

 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;



    public PopulateTable() {



    }



 protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {



  ArrayList<Countries> country=new ArrayList<Countries>();

  country=FetchData.getAllCountries();

  Gson gson = new Gson();

  JsonElement element = gson.toJsonTree(country, new TypeToken<List<Countries>>() {}.getType());



  JsonArray jsonArray = element.getAsJsonArray();

  response.setContentType("application/json");

  response.getWriter().print(jsonArray);

 }

 protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

 }


}
```

Coutries.java

```
  /*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package Countries;

public class Countries {



 public Countries(String code,String name, String continent,String region,int population, String capital )

        {     

          this.setCode(code);

          this.setName(name);
          this.setContinent(continent);

          this.setRegion(region);

          this.setPopulation(population);

          this.setCapital(capital);

        }



 public Countries() {


 }


    private String code;

    private String name;

    private String continent;

    private String region;

    private int population;  

    private String capital;





    public void setCode(String code) {

  this.code = code;

 }

 public String getCode() {

  return code;

 }



 public void setName(String name) {

  this.name = name;

 }



 public String getName() {

  return name;

 }



 public void setContinent(String continent) {

  this.continent = continent;

        }



 public String getContinent() {

  return continent;

 }



 public void setRegion(String region) {

  this.region = region;

 }



 public String getRegion() {

  return region;

 }





 public void setPopulation(int population) {

  this.population = population;

 }



 public int getPopulation() {

  return population;

 }





 public void setCapital(String capital) {

  this.capital = capital;

 }



 public String getCapital() {

  return capital;

 }

}
```

here is a image for mysql database and its table.
[image: this is a image which contain database information]

Comment: AJAX call and database access should be completely separate of each other. Test/check if wiether part works on it's own. Step through both the JavaScript (in the browser's debugger) and the Java (in your IDE).

Answer (score 0):

You can first try to figure out where the actual problem is occurring. 
- First you can check if the data is actually being retrieved from database. In servlet doGet method you iterate over country list and print its data using system.out.println 
- If you are able to retrieve data then on the client side see that proper Json data is coming. You can check response on client side using firebug.
- In the jQuery code use console.log to check whether the data is coming or not. You can put log statement before and after the `if(responseJson!=null)` to check if data is actually null or not. 
- If data is not null then there must be some issue with the format in which data is coming or how you are iterating over the data.